# Django: Deal Wizard and Auto ID

Tags: django, django-forms, django-formwizard

Say I have field named `address_line_1` at form, once I render this it is generated as such:

```
<input id="id_1-address_line_1" type="text" name="1-address_line_1">
```

And I use this form at different pages however it doesn't have a consistency, one is generated as `id_1-address_line_1` while some other same form at another view as `id_1-address_line_1` thus it hurty my javascript side. How can I drop the `id_X` part so that the rendered id has the exact same name as the field name `address_line_1`

Answer (score 0):

```
FormClass(prefix="prefix_to_display")
```

Comment: You don't construct the forms directly with wizards.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of `id_` by using the [`auto_id`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#configuring-form-elements-html-id-attributes-and-label-tags) parameter. In your view class:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self, step=None):
    kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs(step)
    kwargs['auto_id'] = True
    return kwargs
```

In order to get rid of the `X-` you'll have to render the fields manually. This can be done with custom templates, or in the field definitions:

```
address_line_1 = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'address_line_1'})
)
```